# Not Able To Fetch Value From Parent Field In Child Class

Tags: trigger

I'm trying to write a trigger to display a error message on Quote Page, where in I'm facing an issue.

This is what I have written :

```
for(sObject obj: trigger.new)        
{        
    Quote q = (Quote)obj;  
    Quote qOld = (Quote)Trigger.oldMap.get(q.ID);         
    if(u1.profile.name != 'SDS Integration Profile' && u1.profile.name != 'System Administrator' 
        && q.Opportunity.Account.Block_Status_c = 'Block' && (q.Active__c = qOld.Active__c))      
        q.addError('________________'); 
}
```

Now `Block_Status__c` is an Account Field which I'mm not able to use here in QuoteHandler Class.

How do I do this ?

Comment: Are you sure that `q.Opportunity.Account.Block_Status_c` is a valid relationship? Why aren't you assigning `trigger.new` instances directly to `Quote`?

Comment: Also, do you have person accounts enabled in your org? If this is a field on the contact record, make sure you use `__pc` rather than `__c`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot traverse relationships / access the field of the object referenced in the look up from the trigger.new context variable. You will have to query and get details of the look-up before using. So you can do something like this:

```
//Query the Opportunity.Account.Block_Status_c field and store it in a map.
map<id, quote> quoteMap = new map<id, quote>([SELECT id, Opportunity.Account.Block_Status_c from quote where id in : trigger.newMap.keySet()]);

for(sObject obj: trigger.new)        
{        
    Quote q = (Quote)obj;  
    Quote qOld = (Quote)Trigger.oldMap.get(q.ID);
    //Get the value from the map
    if(u1.profile.name != 'SDS Integration Profile' && u1.profile.name != 'System Administrator' 
        && quoteMap.get(q.Id).Opportunity.Account.Block_Status_c = 'Block' && (q.Active__c = qOld.Active__c))      
        q.addError('________________'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your quotes are related to accounts, and you're wanting to load the `Block_Status__c` field for the related accounts, you need to do the query yourself, related fields are not pulled into the trigger automatically.

You could add a formula field to pull the value onto the quote object, but if you need other fields as well then you're best off doing the query.

Pseudocode would be something like (assuming it's an update trigger since you're using `oldMap`):

```
Map<Id, String> statuses = new Map<Id, String>();

for(Quote q : trigger.new)
{
  statuses.Put(q.Id, null);
}

for(Quote q : [select Id, Opportunity.Account.Block_Status__c from Quote where Id in : statuses.keySet()])
{
  status.put(q.Id, q.Opportunity.Account.Block_Status__c);
}

// now you have a map to use:

for(Quote q : trigger.new)        
{        
  Quote qOld = Trigger.oldMap.get(q.ID);         
  if(u1.profile.name != 'SDS Integration Profile' && u1.profile.name != 'System Administrator' 
    && statuses.get(q.id) = 'Block' && (q.Active__c = qOld.Active__c))
  {
    q.addError('________________'); 
  }
}
```